# After rotating screen 180 degrees on MacBook Pro scaling does not work

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

Reprosteps:

1. Go to system prefs
2. Hold CMD and OPT and click on Display
3. Screen rotation appears as option - select 180 degrees
4. Select one of the scaling options

Expected: 
Scaling changes.

Actual:
Nothing changes.

Is there any other way to do this? Some terminal magic? 3rd party software?

MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2019)
Catalina 10.15.4 (19E287)

Comment: Please add the version of macOS you are using and the model of MacBook Pro to your original question

Comment: done. MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2019) 10.15.4 (19E287)